# Problems with accessing files on a Sansa Clip mp3 player

Tags: linux-mint, mount, sansa

I have problems with accessing my mp3 player (Sansa Clip) on my Linux Mint. When I plug in the player, it does mount, but seems to be empty - well -- there are built in directories and config files, here goes tree output:

```
.
├── AUDIBLE
├── AUDIOBOOKS
├── DID.bin
├── MTABLE.SYS
├── MUSIC
├── PODCASTS
├── RECORD
│   ├── FM
│   └── VOICE
├── RES_INFO.SYS
├── SYS_CONF.SYS
└── version.sdk

7 directories, 5 files
```

I have no idea what's going on; I've changed the USB mode to MSC, but it didn't help.

P.S.
When I tried to open it with banshee - it displayed on the bottom bar that there are no audio files, no video files, 2.3GB of "other files" and 5GB of free space.

Comment: Shouldn't music be under `MUSIC`? If it mounts, it must be ok, `find . -iname '*.mp3'` should find the files.

Comment: One thing I've noticed with some players - if you put files on when the player is in MSC mode, they won't display when in MTP mode and vice-versa. Try putting the clip in MTP mode and see if you can see the files that way.

Comment: I've read that MSC/MTP issue about Sansa players in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar device, the Sansa Fuze, in MSC mode. If it's mounting correctly you should see mention of it in the kernel log via the `dmesg` command:

```
$ dmesg
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
  Vendor: Generic   Model: Storage Device    Rev: 0.00
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 02
sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdd
sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
usb-storage: device scan complete
  Vendor: Rockbox   Model: Internal Storage  Rev: 0.00
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 04
SCSI device sde: 15462400 512-byte hdwr sectors (7917 MB)
sde: Write Protect is off
sde: Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
sde: assuming drive cache: write through
```

Assuming the device is detected correctly I'd check it out using the terminal, at least initially.

#### is it mounted?

Based on the output above, the device was assigned `/dev/sde`, so we should see a mount for that assignment:

```
/dev/sde on /media/SANSA FUZE type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,shortname=winnt,uid=0)
```

#### is the mount working?

Try changing directories, onto the device. Notice above, the device is mounted at `/media/SANZA FUZE`.

```
$ cd /media/SANSA\ FUZE/

$ pwd
/media/SANSA FUZE

$  ls -l
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 32768 Dec 28  2009 Music
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 32768 Dec 28  2009 Photo
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 32768 May  6 09:38 Podcasts
```

#### access a file?

Now I'd `cd` to a directory such as Podcasts and see if I can see any files on the device.

Once I've confirmed that there's an actual mp3 file on the device like so:

```
$ ls 
sn0395.mp3

$ file sn0395.mp3
sn0395.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kBits, 44.1 kHz, Monaural
```

Assuming the above is fine, I'd double check in the file browser (Nautilus and/or MATE) as well.

#### files set to hidden

On very rare occassions I've had to take the device into a windows system because I couldn't see any of the files on the device either. When I went into Windows I noticed that the files and/or some of the directories had their attributes set to hidden. In Windows Explorer I set them to un-hidden and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me on Linux Mint with Sony Mp3 Player and hidden files that I could not delete otherwise:

```
sudo fdisk -l # To located usb device

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

    /dev/sdb1               7      944127     1888242    b  W95 FAT32*        #Note: 32bit

sudo umount /dev/sdb1

sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1 #Use 32 or 16 dependent on your version
```